# Can I get a summer job in the US if I study abroad?

Tags: usa

I'm a US citizen but I'm doing my Bachelor's abroad. I will be going back to the US in the summer and I wanted to get a summer job but I am not sure how to apply since I live abroad and applications are all for people who live in the US
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Do you know yet what your US address will be? You might be overthinking this. As you're a citizen, I wouldn't expect most employers to care about whether or not you're in the US during the rest of the year. They just want you present when you're working, right?

Comment: @DanGetz I will be staying with family. Should I put their address as my own?

Comment: Yes, if you're staying with them, that's your address (at least while you're staying with them.)

Comment: You will have to present your passport and Social Security card to your employer when you start work, so make sure you have both of these available.

Answer (score 2):

Some things you can do:

- Clearly indicate that you are a US citizen and are authorized to work in the US
- Clearly indicate that you are currently living abroad, however you will be returning to the US on / before summer
- Clearly indicate that you will need to interview via Skype / Google / whatever else, since you currently reside *outside* of the US. Indicate your time zone if you don't plan on just staying up for the interviews

The chief point is clearly indicating that you are a US citizen and can work legally in the US. But don't stop there, put some stuff in your cover letter about your adventures abroad, how they changed you, what you learned. Present yourself as a [citizen of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_citizenship), it's an advantage :)

Answer (score 1):

Applications are for people living in the US for reasons that is hard to get a visa for people that don't. But you don't need a visa, so this limitation doesn't apply to you.

Just write down a US contact address (I'm sure you have some friends or relatives in the US whose address you can give), and get a US phone number (Skype or Google Voice, or similar) and you're golden.